# How can I update a score column in Table A using a record count from Table B?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a `posts` table and a `likes` table. Many users can like a post. The `posts` table has a denormalized `likesScore` column that represents the number of `likes` a post has. I would like to update the `posts.likesScore` table by doing a `COUNT(*)` on the `likes` table `@postId`.

I have an idea of how to do it, but I can't get the syntax right:

```
UPDATE posts
SET likesScore = ...
WHERE posts.id = @postId
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MySQL UPDATE statements support JOINs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) - use:

```
UPDATE POSTS p 
       JOIN (SELECT t.postid,
                    COUNT(*) AS cnt
               FROM LIKES t
           GROUP BY t.postid) l ON l.postid = p.postid
   SET likesscore = l.cnt
```

The standard means is to use a subquery, but that requires correlation in the subquery *and* filtration in the WHERE clause -- otherwise there's a risk of updating records that don't have references in supporting tables.

I prefer not to store the count in a table, using a view because there's a lot of risk of the count being out of sync with the data every time a LIKE in this case is made.

Comment: @OMG Ponies, many thanks. Can I ask you what you use "group by" in the sub query? Can't I just use "where postId = @postId" ? Also, you said use joins, but I can't see a join in that query, or at least the key word "join"... am I missing something?

Comment: I think you meant to JOIN the subquery, instead of using the comma-separated table list

Comment: @mel: Check the update.  The group by is to make sure the count value is accurate.  The benefit to the INNER JOIN is that you don't need the WHERE clause -- it's redundant in this case.  For more info on JOINs: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: @OMG Ponies, I was looking into views, as you suggested. I don't understand whether or not they would be practical in a case where I want to display many posts and each post's number of likes. I'm not sure how or if I could incorporate a view into a query that selects all posts, hence why a denormalized column seems the easiest option. Would you still use a view for that purpose given this requirement?

Comment: @mel: inline or non-materialized, yes - I would use views over storing the value due to sync issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE posts
SET likesScore = (SELECT count(*) FROM likes WHERE likes.id=posts.id)
WHERE ...
```